# Azure Search not recognizing Integrated Change Tracking on SQL Server Database

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am currently setting up our second Azure Search service.  I am making it identical to our existing one, just in a different region.

I'm using the portal Import Data function to set up my index.  For the Data Source, I have configured it to connect to my Azure SQL Database and table, which definitely has Integrated Change Tracking turned on.  Further, it's the exact same database and table that I'm connected to and indexing from in my existing Azure Search service.

The issue is that when I get to the "Create an Indexer" step, I get the message that says "Consider enabling integrated change tracking on your database..."  In other words, it doesn't think I have change tracking on this database.  I definitely do, and our other Azure Search Service recognizes this just fine on the exact same database.

Any idea what's going on here?  How can I get this Data Source to be recognized as having Change Tracking turned on, and why isn't it doing so when all is working as expected in our existing Search service with identical set up?

Answer (score 0):

We will investigate. In the meantime, please try creating your datasource and indexer programmatically using the REST API or .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

When I was experiencing this problem, I tried creating the search service via "Add Azure Search" in Azure portal > SQL database.

Using that wizard I was able to create the search data source, index & indexer.

Update: I opened a ticket with Azure support, and when trying to get more information to provide to them, I tried to reproduce the problem (create a data source via REST API), but the expected failure did not happen ("Change tracking not enabled for table..." despite it being enabled). This makes me think there was something wrong with internal Azure code that was fixed in the meantime.